# Value button after Ajax execution

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a problem loading the value in the button. The button button appears in the DOM after ajax and jquery returns an empty value.

Please help me to do what needs to be done to get value. I also tried to reload the DOM, but it occurs to me that the reload will be done the same way after the alert reports an empty value. Thank you

```
$ (document) .ready (function () {
   $ ("button"). click (function () {
       var fired_button = $ (this) .val ();
       alert (fired_button);
   });
});



function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) { 
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "parcelshop.php?stat=<?php echo $stat;?>&q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

parcelshop.php

```
 echo "<div id=\"".$pole['KTMID']."\" style=\"color:black; position: relative;padding:10px; margin:4px 4px 10px 4px; line-height: 20px; background-color:#e2e3e4; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; width:".$sirka."; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15); box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);\"><a class=\"marker-link\" id=\"aa".$pole['KTMID']."\" data-markerid=\"".$igps."\" href=\"#\"><img alt=\"Mapa\" title=\"Zobrazit PPL Parcelshop na mapě.\" src=\"images/gmap.png\" style=\"width:50px; position:absolute; top:10px; right: 10px\" class=\"gmaps\"></a>".$pole['customerName1']."<br />".$pole['street1']."<br />".$pole['zipCode']." ".$pole['city']." (".$pole['KTMID'].")<br />".$phone."<input value=\"".$pole['gpse']."\" id=\"gpse[]\" hidden><input value=\"".$pole['gpsn']."\" id=\"gpsn[]\" hidden><br /><br /><a href=\"#\" id=\"aaa".$pole['KTMID']."\"  class=\"aaa\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('a".$pole['KTMID']."').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."skr').style.display='contents';document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."skr').style.textDecoration='underline';document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."').style.display='none';\" style=\"text-decoration: underline;margin-bottom:30px;\">Otevírací doba</a><a href=\"#\" id=\"aaa".$pole['KTMID']."skr\"  class=\"aaa\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('a".$pole['KTMID']."').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."skr').style.display='none';document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."').style.display='contents';document.getElementById('aaa".$pole['KTMID']."').style.textDecoration='underline';\" style=\"margin-bottom:30px; display: none;\">Otevírací doba (skryj)</a><div id=\"a".$pole['KTMID']."\" style=\"display: none\"><br /><table>".$oteviraci_doba."</table></div><br><button id=\"button".$pole['KTMID']."\" value=\"button".$pole['KTMID']."\" onclick=\"showKTM('".$pole['customerName1'].", ".$pole['street1'].", ".$pole['zipCode'].", ".$pole['city']."','".$pole['KTMID']."');\" style=\"position: absolute; right:10px; bottom:10px; padding:10px; color: white; background-color: #0442A5;\" class=\"tlacitko\" type=\"button\">Zvolit</button><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ktm\" value=\"".$pole['KTMID']."\" id=\"".$pole['KTMID']."\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ktm_psc\" value=\"".$pole['zipCode']."\" id=\"".$pole['zipCode']."\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ktm_stat\" value=\"".$pole['Country']."\" id=\"".$pole['Country']."\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"ktm_adresa\" name=\"ktm_adresa\" value=\"".$pole['KTMID'].",".$pole['customerName1'].",".$pole['street1'].",".$pole['zipCode']." ".$pole['city']."\"></div>";       }
    
    
    //$gps[] = $pole['gpsn'].",".$pole['gpse'];
    $igps ++;
    //$oteviraci_doba = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $oteviraci_doba);
    $nazev_ktm = str_replace(",", "", $pole['customerName1']);
    $ulice_ktm = str_replace(",", "", $pole['street1']);
    $tlacitko = "<button id=\"button".$pole['KTMID']."\" value=\"button".$pole['KTMID']."\" onclick=\"showKTM('".$pole['customerName1'].", ".$pole['street1'].", ".$pole['zipCode'].", ".$pole['city']."','".$pole['KTMID']."');\" style=\"position: absolute; right:10px; bottom:10px; padding:10px; color: white; background-color: #0442A5;\" class=\"tlacitko\" type=\"button\">Zvolit</button>";
    $margin = "style=\"margin-bottom:40px;\"";
    $gps[] = $pole['gpsn'].",,".$pole['gpse'].",,".$nazev_ktm."<br>".$ulice_ktm."<br>".$pole['zipCode']." ".$pole['city']."<br>".$phone."<br><br>".htmlentities($tlacitko)."<table ".htmlentities($margin).">".htmlentities($oteviraci_doba)."</table>,,".$pole['KTMID'].",,1".$igps.",,".$pole['customerName1'];




 <input type="hidden" id="point" name="point" value="<?php
foreach ($gps as $key) {
echo $key."---";
```

The problem is that I need to replace onlick due to CSP. Maybe you'll have a better solution than I suppose.

---

this already works, but I get an alert twice

empty for the first time and with a value for the second time

**why do I see it twice and why is it empty for the first time?**

```
$(document).on("click","button",function() {
            var fired_button = $(this).val();
            alert(fired_button);

        });
```

Comment: can u post html code here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you show your HTML code too, please?

Comment: You post the code for alert (and it work), post ajax code.

Comment: Hard to understand what you actually mean here. You are probably looking for _event delegation_ though.

Comment: I added code. And I've already figured something out.